# Build message from properties

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, properties

I've got this propery elements:

```
   Ausloesungsart.UNDEFINED= \= Unbekannt
   Ausloesungsart.FIS=0 \= FIS
   Ausloesungsart.MANUELL=1 \= Manuell
```

but it gets displayed on the website like

```
Ausloesungsart.UNDEFINED
Ausloesungsart.FIS
Ausloesungsart.MANUELL
```

instead of the assigned String.

Is it probably due to this method to build the String, that it gets displayed plain without resolving the properties?

```
public String getCanonicalName() {
    return Ausloesungsart.class.getName() + "." + getArt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To read properties file, you should use `Properties load` method, just like that:

```
FileReader reader=new FileReader("foo.properties");  

Properties p=new Properties();  
p.load(reader);  

System.out.println(p.getProperty("Ausloesungsart.FIS"));  
System.out.println(p.getProperty("Ausloesungsart.UNDEFINED"));
```

hope i didn't misunderstand your question.

Comment: I've solved this error with writing a converter class and adding the convert tag with the newly created id of the converter.  Using jsf/core tag.